# HTML - how to display local data in img tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an editable div and a user can paste a picture copied from Office Word. After doing so an image-tag can be seen in the source code, but the path does not work anymore. If I just enter the source link into to the browser, I can see the image. How to modify the link to make it work?

HTML

```
<img src="file:///C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Temp/msohtmlclip1/01/clip_image002.jpg" v:shapes="Grafik_x0020_1">
```

Comment: Have you got a jsFiddle example or link?

Comment: @Vector — What good would that do? You don't have the file on your hard drive!

Comment: @Vector [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddYTz/)

Comment: @Quentin What good would looking at the OP's code do?? is that really what you're asking?

Comment: @Vector — We can see the code. It is in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't open local file in site without user interaction. Browser won't allow that, because it would be great security flaw.